# How to specify resolvers dependencies in webpack?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, webpack

I'm trying to switch from RequireJs to webpack to deal with js loading, sass processing & other stuff like that.

In RequireJs it's possible to specify dependencies for modules

```
// file.js
require(['moduleA','moduleB'],function(A,B) {
    ...
}
```

And I want to specify that moduleA requires jquery for example

```
// requirejs.config.js
require.config({
    ...
    shim:{
        moduleA:{
            deps:['jquery']
        } 
    }
})
```

I'm trying to find a way to do the same thing in webpack

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    entry: toObject(glob.sync('src/**/*.js*')),
    output: {
        path: './bin',
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'moduleA': '/path/to/moduleA',
            ...
        }
    }
};

function toObject(paths) {
    // I return an object of paths
}
```

But I can't find a way to specify that moduleA needs another module !

Does anyone has a clue here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to. You just `require()` whatever module you need, and it would be available.

The reason you need to do this with RequireJS is that RequireJS is asynchronous, modules are loaded asynchronously, and thus it needs to know what to load first. Webpack (and CommonJS in general) is synchronous. By the time you enter the module, everything is already loaded.

Comment: Thak you for the answer. If I understand, that means that If my moduleA requires a moduleB that requires a moduleC, i just have to require moduleC in moduleB, and moduleB in moduleA ?

Comment: But if I require('bootstrap/js/collapse'); and collapse require Jquery, I can't edit my vendors files to specify that bootstrap js needs jquery, i got "jsone.js:10515 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(…)"

Comment: We use `shim` in RequireJS' configuration for a *third-party* script that should be loaded by RequireJS but *does not operate under a formal module system*, and so it does not call `require`. An excellent example of this is Bootstrap, which needs jQuery: we put a shim that declares a dependency on `jquery`, and so RequireJS loads jQuery before it loads Bootstrap, and all is well. So when you say "just `require()`, the upshot is "just modify Bootstrap to call `require()`. I don't know about you, but I avoid modifying third-party libraries unless there's absolutely no other solution.

Comment: If one is to counter is that it is okay to edit `moduleA` to make it work with webpack because it is not a third-party library, then the OP should not be using `shim` in the first place because the correct way to write `moduleA` as an AMD module is to use a proper `define` call, not to write a `shim` configuration for it.